# Auto draft emails in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I’m trying to figure out if there is an action in outlook 365 rules to open a draft email in a new window using a template? Basically I want to set up an auto reply, but ensure I have a chance to look the message over before sending it. Before anyone asks I only get 1-2 of these messages every week so I know I won’t get overwhelmed.

I’m willing to write honest to god code if something like a python script would help me achieve this.

Comment: You could create a signature and put all the text in there. All you have to do is reply, then change the signature to the one with the text and then you can edit the draft like you would normally do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can only create a rule that uses a template to automatically reply to mail in the outlook client, but we can't create a rule to save to the draft. As LPChip mentioned, we can [create a signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2) and write the content you want to reply to in the signature. Then manually click reply after you receive the email, and then [add the signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2#:%7E:text=to%20your%20signature.-,Insert%20a%20signature%20manually,-If%20you%20don%27t), so that you can achieve the purpose of checking the email content before replying.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.